# google-api-javascript-client : How to get contents of file using Drive API?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

First off, if there is a question/answer that solves my problem already then I sincerely apologize for creating a new one. However, I have been searching for 3 days now, and have not found an answer...

My problem is, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to pull the contents of a file(any file). From reading the docs I've discovered that my returned file resource object is supposed to have a property named "downloadUrl", and from this I should be able to access the file contents.

None of the file resource objects that are returned to me(via gapi.client.request) have this field/property. Below is the function I am using to get a file.
Can someone please help point me in the right direction? I have to have this demo done by Monday and I've been stuck on this for 2 days....

Here is the code for my get function :

```
Client.getFileContent = function getFileContent() {
     gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
          var request = gapi.client.request({
               path : '/drive/v2/files/1QmaofXyVqnw6ODXHE5KWlUTcWbA9KkLyb-lBdh_FLUs',
               method : 'GET',
               params : {
                    projection: "FULL"
               }
          });
          request.execute(function(response) {
               console.log(response);   
          });
     });
};
```

The file resource object that is returned to me does not have the downloadUrl property.

As requested, here is the response object I get back for a text file. Note, I replaced some of the ids with "fileid" for posting here.

```
"kind": "drive#file",
   "id": "fileID",
   "etag": "\"-tJAWr_lbRQU2o8gZ0X7BCBIlVk/MTM0MjYyODQ1MTQ2Nw\"",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileID",
   "alternateLink": "https://docs.google.com/document/d/fileID/edit",
   "embedLink": "https://docs.google.com/document/d/fileID/preview",
   "thumbnailLink": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/vt?gd=true&id=fileID&v=1&s=AMedNnoAAAAAUAfLhbYIDsNIn40k7DfRYBsrquijmCii&sz=s220",
   "permissionsLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileID/permissions",
   "title": "Copied filed.txt",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document",
   "labels": {
    "starred": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "trashed": false,
    "restricted": false,
    "viewed": true
   },
   "createdDate": "2012-07-18T16:20:51.132Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2012-07-18T16:20:51.467Z",
   "modifiedByMeDate": "2012-07-18T16:20:51.467Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2012-07-18T16:20:51.467Z",
   "parents": [
    {
     "kind": "drive#parentReference",
     "id": "0AAAYYkwdgVqHUk9PVA",
     "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileID/parents/0AAAYYkwdgVqHUk9PVA",
     "parentLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AAAYYkwdgVqHUk9PVA",
     "isRoot": true
    }
   ],
   "exportLinks": {
    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=fileID&exportFormat=odt",
    "application/msword": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=fileID&exportFormat=doc",
    "text/html": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=fileID&exportFormat=html",
    "application/rtf": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=fileID&exportFormat=rtf",
    "text/plain": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=fileID&exportFormat=txt",
    "application/pdf": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=fileID&exportFormat=pdf"
   },
   "userPermission": {
    "kind": "drive#permission",
    "etag": "\"-tJAWr_lbRQU2o8gZ0X7BCBIlVk/9STkNeCmz61YXorH3hoJimnEgfM\"",
    "id": "current",
    "role": "owner",
    "type": "user"
   },
   "quotaBytesUsed": "0",
   "ownerNames": [
    "Joshua.morine"
   ],
   "lastModifyingUserName": "Joshua.morine",
   "editable": true,
   "writersCanShare": true
  }
```

Comment: Can you also paste the content of response so that we can take a look? Please make sure to strip off any private data. FYI, only files that have content stored in Drive (images, pdf, etc.) will have a downloadUrl.

Comment: Wow. Thank you Alain. I just uploaded a .png to the drive to check what you said, and sure enough there was a downloadUrl. So, how is one supposed to get content from text files and other documents? I will post the response object I get in a few minutes...

Comment: From the metadata you posted, you are trying to get the content of a Google Document. This is not possible directly (as the content is stored in a private format), but you can use the various exportLinks to export in a format understood by your application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For native Google documents (Google Spreadsheet, Presentation etc...) we don;t provide a downloadUrl as these can't really be downloaded as files in their native format. Instead you'll have to use one of the URLs in the list of **exportLinks** which provides URLs to download the Google Documents in a few different export formats.

In your case, a Google Documents the following can be used:

```
"exportLinks": {
    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=fileID&exportFormat=odt",
    "application/msword": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=fileID&exportFormat=doc",
    "text/html": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=fileID&exportFormat=html",
    "application/rtf": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=fileID&exportFormat=rtf",
    "text/plain": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=fileID&exportFormat=txt",
    "application/pdf": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=fileID&exportFormat=pdf"
   }
```

Comment: Okay, thats what I thought, to use the exportLinks that is. However, could you point me in the right direction for accessing these links? I keep getting a (405) method not found... I tried using the CORS request method as described in the api docs. I'm really confused. Sorry if I missed something obvious...

Comment: However, based on this info and what my digging has revealed, accessing the exportLinks is not what I want. I actually want to access the Google Docs and Spreadsheets. So now I just have to figure out how to work with the Docs API in js. Or, is that possible?

Comment: @JoshuaMorine Could you please have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578020/how-to-programmatically-manipulate-native-google-doc-files/11588814#comment15371184_11588814 and let me know if that answers it.

Comment: Thank you for the help and information. This has answered all of my javascript questions, although, the company's decision is to forget using JS and work from a Java standpoint. Which means I have to learn Java now... Thanks again though!

Answer (score 3):

The meta-data function you are looking for is actually:

```
request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
    'fileId': fileId
});
```

This one produces a result with the downloadUrl that you're referring to. Then it's easy to grab the file using any HTTP request.

Comment: The download link does not exist for Google doc files like spreadsheets or docs -- it only appears for files that have been uploaded to drive.