# Is it possible to update a Google Docs file with data from a Microsoft Office file using the convert field?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'd like to be able to edit Google Docs files remotely.  I can export the file into an editable format such as Office, but am having trouble stuffing the edited data back.  I could always delete the original file and replace it by uploading the new file and coverting it back to Google Docs format but that would erase all of the revision history.

The API seems to indicate that the Files Update function supports the convert field, but I haven't had any success getting it to work.  Is this possible?

In my tests, I have a Google Presentation and am trying to update it with an MS PPTX file in the binary data, setting the mime type to "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation" and setting convert=true, all using the Objective - C library for Drive.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the mimeType empty, and set convert=true. With convert=true, it can only be converted to one type of Google Docs.

Yes, you will lose the revision history.