# edit google document remotely

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to add a feature to my website as follows:

Clicking a button appends text to a Google document.

Obviously I will need to create an Apps Script in the drive. **The question is how to trigger the Apps Script from my website.** You can assume that I am the owner of the drive/document and so have permissions to edit it in any way I like.

I have looked at these topics:

1. [Workarounds : How to edit native google documents programatcally?item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713630/workarounds-how-to-edit-native-google-documents-programatcally)
2. [How to programmatically manipulate native google doc files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578020/how-to-programmatically-manipulate-native-google-doc-files)

It seems they are all actions performed from the drive itself and not triggered remotely.

I have also looked up the Apps Script API in Google but have not found a way to do this. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

First write an Apps script that changes your desired document. Then deploy it as a web-app [running as you](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#permissions) that anyone has access, even anonymous. Check out [the guides](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content) at Apps Script page to see how to write your script as a web-app.

Your script will then have a public url, which you can call from your website and have it run "remotely" normally.

Comment: It works, but I am getting a 'xmlhttprequest cannot load no 'access-control-allow-origin' error. Do you know what the script should return to the client?

Comment: You should not have this problem. Can you share an example with the problem (accessing an Apps Script public url)?

Comment: It's OK, my bad. I was running the client from localhost instead of the actual ip address

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. About "what the script should return to the client" it depends on what you've coded on your Apps Script. As I mentioned on another comment, I suggest you keep it simple with [ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content?hl=pt-br), possibly just returning a plain text "OK".

Comment: that's exactly what I did :-)

Answer (score 4):

To provide an example of what Henrique suggests, here is a [small webapp](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyExV6eMLr87hKtAIwxDVcC--Y66GKSZoqyrb6xZ8vd39QqVB8/exec) that adds text to a [publicly viewable document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1THzBTURxGr2CdUmcZ7i2zD-RM8I3im2JCSHI3BHlkeM/edit?usp=sharing) I own (it doesn't need to be public except for anyone here to check it works !)

I wrote it using UiApp but you could of course use HTMLService if you prefer...

[image]

The app runs as me but is accessible to anyone even anonymous.

```
// publicly viewable test doc url : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1THzBTURxGr2CdUmcZ7i2zD-RM8I3im2JCSHI3BHlkeM/edit

function doGet(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('docEdit');
  var panel = app.createAbsolutePanel().setSize('100%','100%').setStyleAttributes({'padding':'40px','backgroundColor':'lightBlue'});
  var text = app.createTextArea().setName('text').setPixelSize(500,300);
  var grid = app.createFlexTable().setId('grid');
  grid.setText(0,0,'Add your text').setWidget(1,0,text);  
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('writeText').addCallbackElement(panel);
  grid.setWidget(2,0,app.createButton('update document',handler).setId('btn'));
  app.add(panel.add(grid));
  return app;
}

function writeText(e){
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('1THzBTURxGr2CdUmcZ7i2zD-RM8I3im2JCSHI3BHlkeM');
  var now = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'MMM/dd/yyyy @ hh:mm:ss');
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.appendParagraph('Append text on '+now+' : '+e.parameter.text);
  doc.saveAndClose();
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var grid = app.getElementById('grid');
  grid.setWidget(3,0,app.createHTML('Thanks,<br>Your text has been added to the document'));
  app.getElementById('btn').setEnabled(false).setHTML('Button disabled');
  return app;
}
```

Comment: I think [ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content) is better suited for his case, since he'll be calling it from regular javascript on his website.

Comment: I would agree if he needed to return data from the doc but as I understand the request - he just needs to write to the document so documentApp service is the only one involved. The webapp and its UI are just there to illustrate a working example..