# store email ids in google documnet

Tags: html, google-docs

I have a static HTML page containing a form to subscribe to an email list by entering an email address. Since I have no database to store the email addresses received through the form, is there any way to capture and store those email addresses into a Google Document?

```
Subscribe for newsletter<br/>

<input type="text" placeholder="enter email id" />
<button>
Subscribe
</button>
```

Comment: see link - http://www.cnet.com/how-to/save-gmail-messages-in-google-docs/   but what function you write on button's click ? I think instead it try to use google forms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [edit google document remotely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26679984/edit-google-document-remotely)